# Add Content Editor Web Part (JS) hide "Chrome type" = none

Tags: javascript, web-part

What is missing in the code to hide "Chrome type" = none?

[image]

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/RU_test';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/RU_test/SitePages/Test.aspx';
function addWebPart() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' + 
    '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
    ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
    ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
    '<Title>Template</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
    '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
    '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
    '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
    '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
    '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
    '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
    '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
    '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
    '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
    '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
    'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
    '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
    '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + '/sites/RU_test/SiteAssets/template.js</ContentLink>' + 
    '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
    '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
    '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';
var oWebPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();
limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebPart, 'Left', 1);
clientContext.load(oWebPart);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert('Web Part added: ' + oWebPart.get_title());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello the Chrome Type is managed by the tag

```
**<FrameType>None</FrameType>**
```

which in your code is set to

```
<FrameType>Default</FrameType>
```

you need to set it as none then it will work as aspected.